# Cant Find Base SDK Drop down - Xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, xcode4.2, base-sdk

I had a problem with *base SDK* on my **Xcode 4.2**. I can not see the drop down menu on on Base SDK field. After I clicked then it became editable.  I cannot see the drop down list. Why is that?

Thank a lot.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have changed from "Show Values" mode to "Show Definitions" mode. You can change back to "Show Values" mode through the `Editor` menu. (Editor -> Show Values)

[image]

Comment: how did you get that window?

can you send me the navigation route like this??
XXX----> xxxx -----> xxxxx--->> 

can you ??

thank A lot.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've messed up your project settings. You are debugging on iOS simulator, but releasing for macOS? What king of product is it?!

Try to set to one target only (either iOS or macOS) for all of your modes(debug,release, e.t.c.)...